# GANs for non image data

Tags: references, small-sample, generative-models, gan, data-augmentation

I'm looking to narrow down the subject for my bachelor thesis:
I am currently working on a project, that only offers a small dataset and there will be no more data incoming for now.
What I'm trying to do now, is optimizing my neural net with augmented data, produced by a GAN.

Mostly, I just find GANs that are being used for images. What I am trying to predict are machines that can be used for production.
Does anybody here know about possiblities, sources or other ideas that fit to this topic? Any help would be welcome!

The only source I found, yet is this one:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.00981.pdf

Comment: "What I am trying to predict are machines that can be used for production." What exactly are you trying to predict?

Comment: The attributes of the resources. So I am predicting the different attributes (some are flags, some are values) resulting in a fictive resource and afterwards I run a filter over them, in order to find the resource, that matches the prediction the most

Comment: So, some of your attributes are discrete (binary) and some continuous (?). And I guess you want to predict the machines to be used for production. This seems a classification task from the description, not a generation.

Comment: If I’m not wrong that is tabular data. Did you try to compare your deep learning approach with other models (ex. random forest, gradient boosted trees)?

Comment: If you just have a small dataset, I don’t think you can perform augmentation with a GAN ( trained from scratch ) since from my intuition it could be harder than training the model itself. 
If you have an unbalanced dataset you could try oversampling techniques such as SMOTE